# Is it possible to use the TestNG plugin with Netbeans 6.8?

Tags: java, ide, netbeans, plugins, testng

I downloaded the [TestNG NetBeans Plugin](http://wiki.netbeans.org/TestNG) and tried to install it in my NetBeans 6.8. I'm running NetBeans IDE 6.8 (Build 200912041610).

When I click install, I get this message:

> Some plugins require plugin External
>   Execution Support to be installed. The
>   plugin External Execution Support is
>   requested in version >= 1.19 but only
>   1.18.1 was found.   The following plugin is affected:       TestNG
>   Support
>
> Some plugins require plugin Common
>   Test Runner API to be installed. The
>   plugin Common Test Runner API is
>   requested in version >= 1.13 but only
>   1.12.1 was found.   The following plugin is affected:       TestNG
>   Support
>
> Some plugins require plugin Utilities
>   API to be installed. The plugin Utilities API is requested in version >= 8.0 but only 7.31.2.1 was found.   The following plugin is affected:
>         TestNG Support
>
> Some plugins require plugin
>   org.openide.util.lookup to be
>   installed. The plugin
>   org.openide.util.lookup is requested
>   in version 8.0.   The following plugin
>   is affected:       TestNG Support
>
> Some plugins not installed to avoid
>   potential installation problems.

**Is it possible to use the TestNG plugin with Netbeans 6.8?**

The plugin manager doesn't even seem to know about any of the dependency plugins.  Is the TestNG plugin build against a beta or experimental version? I have updated all of my plugins to the latest versions.

---

## Update

I went ahead and built the module from the Netbeans 6.8 branch.  It installs fine now.  Unfortunately, when I run the tests, I can see the ant output, but the TestNG view says "No tests Executed." I'll keep fiddling with it to see if I can get it working.

Comment: you may want to open a new question regarding your update...  You are more likely to get an answer to new unanswered question than a question which has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a quick look at this.  It appears that the nbm file that you can download from the wiki page that you referenced is compiled against the trunk of the NB sources, not the bits that are released as NetBeans 6.8.

I have sent a note to the developer about this.

You can build the NBM yourself, but it is pretty painful, since you have to get the contrib repository.

Answer (score 1):

This is embarrassing not able to use either the old version of TestNG or new version of TestNG in NetBeans. Any one kindly create a correct TestNG plugin for version 6.8.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think anyone has been working on the TestNG Netbeans plug-in in a while, so I'm not surprised to hear you are running into difficulties.  Try posting your question on their forums?

Otherwise, I continue to work actively on the Eclipse plug-in (new version released a few weeks ago) and TestNG is supported natively by IDEA...

Hope this helps.

Comment: The last changes to this plugin happened around 8 Jan 2010.  It looks like they were bug fixes.

Comment: The official plugin is completely unusable for Ant projects in Netbeans 7.1: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=207886

Comment: There is now some developing going on see http://wiki.netbeans.org/TestNG2012 and an already fixed issue (compile on save for testng) http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=149464